# Android TV - How to implement Navigation Drawer Fixed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-tv

I'm learning to use Leanback.

I need to implement the Header(Navigation Drawer) where the icon should always be visible while collapsing drawer similar to Voot Android TV App

https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdhLM.jpg

any sugestions?